# API to create Exact Target Email Templates

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, email, email-template, ampscript

Is there an API in Exact Target to create an email template from HTML?   I've seen questions on how to create an email from a template, but I want to do the opposite  create a template from HTML.

Ideally this should be a REST or SOAP API, or some kind of AMPScript.

Answer (score 2):

There is an object in the SOAP API called Template which represents an email template in an ExactTarget account. The documentation is here: https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/template/

It says it supports the Create method so the answer to your question is yes.

I do not see anything regarding email templates in the Rest API.